# Converting Hexadecimal to Binary in c programming

Tags: c

I ask the user to input a text, then I store it in input. Then I print the hexadecimal of each character in the text.

However, I also need the binary of the hexadecimal, so is there a way to convert the hexadecimal to a binary?

```
char input[50], ch;
int i = 0;

    printf("Enter Cleartext: ");
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        input[j] = ch;  
        j++;
    }   

    printf("Hex encoding is: \n");
    for(i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("%x ", input[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, convert your hex-string to an `unsigned` value using `strtoul` with a base of `16` (or `0`) and then output the bits of the `unsigned` value. Otherwise you will need (depending on endianess) to either reverse map (little-endian) the bit representation for each "2-hexchar byte" to its binary character string equivalent of 8-charactes of `'0'` and `'1'`. (hint: use `strtoul`, the other will be much longer)

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is you fail to *nul-terminate* `input` in your first loop filling `input` and then in your second loop, you attempt to iterate until `'\0'` is reached -- bad thing happen when you invoke *Undefined Behavior*.

Which brings up the point, read user-input with `fgets()` and you eliminate the risk of failing to *nul-terminate* your input string or in writing beyond you array bound (which you also fail to check).

Once you have the string representation of the hexadecimal number, convert it to `unsigned long` with [`strtoul`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtoul.3.html). (validate the conversion). Once you have the string converted to a number, it doesn't matter whether you want to view it as decimal, hexadecimal, octal or binary, the bits in memory are the same. The only thing that changes is the output format you are looking at them with.

Unfortunately, C doesn't provide a library function to output binary -- you get to write it in a couple of lines.

With that in mind, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for strtoul */
#include <errno.h>  /* for strtoul validation */
#include <limits.h> /* for CHAR_BIT */

#define MAXC 50     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char input[MAXC], 
            *endptr = NULL;     /* for use with strtoul */
    unsigned long u = 0,        /* variable to hold conversion */
            remain = 0;         /* value after shift - are 1-bits present */
    size_t nbits = sizeof u * CHAR_BIT;     /* number of bits in u */

    fputs ("enter cleartext: ", stdout);    /* prompt */
    if (!fgets (input, MAXC, stdin))        /* read input string */
        return 1;

    u = strtoul (input, &endptr, 0);        /* convert to unsigned long */
    if (input == endptr) {                  /* validate digits converted */
        fputs ("error: no digits converted.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (errno) {                       /* validate no over/underflow */
        perror ("strtoul-u");               /* during conversion */
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("decimal: %lu\nbinary : ", u);  /* output decimal value */
    while (nbits--)                         /* loop outputting bits */
        if ((remain = u >> nbits)) 
            putchar ((remain & 1) ? '1' : '0');
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

When converting to integer values the `base` parameter to `strtoul` of `0` allows input to be in decimal, hexadecimal or octal format.

(**note:** `remain` just tests whether there are any `1-bits` left to output and prevents outputting all the leading zeros -- you can change if you want to output the full 64-bits)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/hexbin
enter cleartext: 0xa
decimal: 10
binary : 1010

$ ./bin/hexbin
enter cleartext: 0xff
decimal: 255
binary : 11111111

$ ./bin/hexbin
enter cleartext: 0xdeadbeef
decimal: 3735928559
binary : 11011110101011011011111011101111
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

There were some problems with your code. First of all, `j` wasn't declared and initialized. You were also checking for just `\n` but not checking for `EOF` (End of file) which is encountered when there is no more input to read. And, you were not terminating with `'\0'` character in `input`.

To convert to binary, I used the fact that each character is a 8-bit ASCII and can be represented using integers in range [0, 255]. So I declared a 8-bit character array and used the [int-to-binary conversion logic](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-decimal-binary-conversion/) to get 8-bit binary string for each character.

Here's the link where I tested it: http://ideone.com/ZWXchq

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

void to_binary(int d) {
    int x = d, ind = 7;
    char *buf = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * CHAR_BIT);  // CHAR_BIT in limits.h (value is 8)
    if (buf == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        return;
    }
    memset(buf, '0', 8);

    while (x > 0) {
        int mod_val = x % 2;
        x >>= 1;
        buf[ind--] = '0' + mod_val;
        //printf("%c ", buf[ind + 1]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) printf("%c", buf[i]);
    printf(" ");
    free(buf);
    buf = NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    char input[50], ch;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    printf("Enter Cleartext: ");
    while (1) {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF) break;

        input[j++] = ch;
    }
    input[j] = '\0';

    printf("\nHex encoding is: \n");
    for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("%x ", input[i]);
    }
    printf("\nBinary encoding is: \n");
    for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        to_binary(input[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Need to `free(buf);` at the end of `to_binary` or you leak memory. `sizeof (char)` is always `1`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, ohh yeah, forgot it!

Comment: regarding: `char *buf = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);`   1) the returned type, in C, from`malloc()` is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer, casting just clutters the code.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is always 1,  Multiplying by 1 has absolutely mo effect.  Suggest removing that expression.  3)  the 'magic' number 8 should be: `CHAR_BIT` from the header file: `limits.h` 4) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()`, `calloc()`, and `realloc()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: @user3629249, thanks for constructive comment! Regarding (1) and (2), it's just a habit of writing that way! About (3) I wasn't aware of that, so thanks for mentioning! About (4) yeah we can check that; it would be a bit safer!

Comment: There's no need to cast `'0'` to an `int`; character constants are always `int`s anyway.

Comment: @JL2210, point noted and done the change!

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. limits the length of the user input
3. is much faster than reading one char at a time
4. makes use of a 'nibble' table to speed the display of the binary values

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_INPUT_LEN 50

char *nibbleTable[] =
{
    "0000",
    "0001",
    "0010",
    "0011",
    "0100",
    "0101",
    "0110",
    "0111",
    "1000",
    "1001",
    "1010",
    "1011",
    "1100",
    "1101",
    "1110",
    "1111"
 };

int main( void )
{
    char input[ MAX_INPUT_LEN ];


    printf("Enter Cleartext: ");
    if( !fgets( input, sizeof( input ), stdin )  )
    {
        perror( "fgets failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // remove trailing newline
    input[ strcspn( input, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    printf("Hex encoding is: \n");
    for( size_t i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) 
    {
        printf( "%x ", input[i]);
    }

    puts( "" );

    printf( "binary encoding is: \n" );
    for( size_t i = 0; input[i]; i++ )
    {
        if( input[i+1] != '\0' )
        {
            printf( "%s%s, ", 
                    nibbleTable[ (unsigned)((input[i] >> 4) & 0x0f)], 
                    nibbleTable[ (unsigned)(input[i] & 0x0f)] );
        }

        else
        {
            printf( "%s%s\n", 
                    nibbleTable[ (unsigned)((input[i] >> 4) & 0x0f)], 
                    nibbleTable[ (unsigned)(input[i] & 0x0f)] );
        }
    }

}
```

a typical run of the program:

```
Enter Cleartext: hello old friend
Hex encoding is: 
68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 6f 6c 64 20 66 72 69 65 6e 64 
binary encoding is: 
01101000, 01100101, 01101100, 01101100, 01101111, 00100000, 01101111, 01101100, 01100100, 00100000, 01100110, 01110010, 01101001, 01100101, 01101110, 01100100
```

Comment: That is way better than my answer! And more efficient too! +1